# Importing netbeans j2me projects to eclipse indigo

Tags: java-me

Importing netbeans j2me projects to eclipse indigo

getting error of package builder when trying to import netbeans j2me project to eclipse indigo so plz anyone give solution how to import.

Comment: Plz answer it fast anyone plz help me...